# Orchard CMS - Handler doesn't update the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding, razor, orchardcms

At my orchard module, everything works fine, but unfortunately the database is not updated.

I have defined the view for the admin panel at **Orchard.Web\Modules\Course\Views\EditorTemplates\Parts\Course.cshtml** as bellow:

```
@model Course.Models.CoursePart

<fieldset>
  <legend>Course Fields</legend>

  <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
  </div>
  <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
  </div>

  <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
  </div>
  <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
  </div>


  <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImagePath)
  </div>
  <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImagePath)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImagePath)
  </div>


</fieldset>
```

And the driver as bellow:

```
public class CourseDriver : ContentPartDriver<CoursePart>
    {
        protected override DriverResult Display(CoursePart part,
                                        string displayType,
                                        dynamic shapeHelper)
        {

            return ContentShape("Parts_Course",
                () => shapeHelper.Parts_Course(
                Description: part.Description,
                Title: part.Title,
                ImagePath: part.ImagePath,
                Area: part.Area
                ));
        }

        //GET
        protected override DriverResult Editor(CoursePart part,
                                               dynamic shapeHelper)
        {

            return ContentShape("Parts_Course_Edit",
                () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(
                    TemplateName: "Parts/Course",
                    Model: part,
                    Prefix: Prefix));
        }

        //POST
        protected override DriverResult Editor(CoursePart part,
                                               IUpdateModel updater,
                                               dynamic shapeHelper)
        {
            updater.TryUpdateModel(part, Prefix, null, null);
            return Editor(part, shapeHelper);
        }
    }
```

And the Handler:

```
namespace Course.Handlers
{
    public class CourseHandler: ContentHandler
    {
          public CourseHandler(IRepository<CourseRecord> repository) 
          {
                Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));
          }

    }
}
```

The migration class described bellow is at the  **Orchard.Web\Modules\Course\Migrations.cs** file.

```
namespace Course {
    public class Migrations : DataMigrationImpl {

        public int Create() {
            // Creating table CoursePartRecord
            SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("CourseRecord", table => table
                .ContentPartRecord()
                .Column("Area", DbType.String)
                .Column("Description", DbType.String)
                .Column("Title", DbType.String)
                .Column("ImagePath", DbType.String)
            );

            //Add the AlterPartDefinition lines to the migration in order to make the part
            //attachable to any content type. 
            ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition(
                typeof(CoursePart).Name, cfg => cfg.Attachable());

            return 1;
        }

        public int UpdateFrom1()
        {
            ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("CourseContent", cfg => cfg
              .WithPart("CommonPart")
              .WithPart("RoutePart")
              .WithPart("BodyPart")
              .WithPart("CoursePart")
              .WithPart("CommentsPart")
              .WithPart("TagsPart")
              .WithPart("LocalizationPart")
              .Creatable()
              .Indexed());
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

The models are described bellow:

```
namespace Course.Models
{
    public class CourseRecord : ContentPartRecord
    {
        public virtual String Area { get; set; }

        public virtual String Description { get; set; }
        public virtual String Title { get; set; }

        public virtual String ImagePath { get; set; }

    }


    public class CoursePart : ContentPart<CourseRecord>
    {
        public String Area { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String Title { get; set; }
        public String ImagePath { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I was following the steps according with the example at the orchard documentation: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-content-part.

**Problem:** The database is not created or updated, every property from the record is updated with null values, the `repository.Table` in `CourseHandler` method is always returning a list.

Best regards,
Tito

Comment: Can you show us your migrations class and your CourseRecord class?

Comment: @mdm ,now I already added it. Thanks for noticed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @mdm comment that gave me a hint, and I took a look again at my code Migration code.
And the class `CoursePart` was defined wrongly, since it wasn't writing or reading from the Record.

When I changed it to the code bellow it worked normally:

```
public class CoursePart : ContentPart<CourseRecord>

{
    public String Area
    {
        get { return Record.Area; }
        set { Record.Area = value; }
    }

    [Required]
    public String Description
    {
        get { return Record.Description; }
        set { Record.Description = value; }
    }

    [Required]
    public String Title
    {
        get { return Record.Title; }
        set { Record.Title = value; }
    }

    public String ImagePath
    {
        get { return Record.ImagePath; }
        set { Record.ImagePath = value; }
    }
}
```